# Mathematical model of spread of disease - exponential growth, herd immunity, and normal distribution

Tags: exponential-function, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, estimation

Covid-19 made me speculate of how to mathematically model the spread of a disease. 
So let's say there's some virus that has a basis reproduction number R0 = 3 (so one infected person does infect exactly 3 people (in the following week)). So we get the time (i.e. week)-dependent function of new infections, f(t) = 3^t, which means exponential growth.

Let's say someone who has been infected is immune forever. Then at some point in time there are so many immune people that the reproduction number decreases, e.g. only two people get infected because the third one is already immune.

1) Now my first question is, how to model our function f(t) in order to take this effect into account? And how to calculate the point in time where this effect shows up? 
I know about how to calculate the percentage p of people necessary for herd immunity (p = 1/(1-R0)), but this only says how many people have to be immune in order to have less than one new infection per current infection, it doesn't say anything about the crease of R from R0 = 3 to R<1.

2) I've found many graphs of simulated spreads on the internet, always depicted as the graph of a normal destribution (for example:

[image]

Is the graph the integral of the modified function we are looking for in 1), i.e. is the function in 1) the density function?

3) In such graph, where is the point of herd immunity? I guess it can't be at the peak of the graph, because i.e. for R = 3, we have p = 66% and that would mean that the area of the graph is equal to 132%, which doesn't make any sense...

I'm looking forward to your answers or to discussing my questions with you here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not a normal density depicted but rather a [logistic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution)

Comment: I have voted to close this question using the "needs focus" template.  As written, your question several questions rolled into one, and needs to be distilled into something a little narrower.  I also think that there is a good argument to be made for this question not really being about mathematics, but rather about modeling, which is something that folk in the biology / epidemiology communities might better be able to answer.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thanks for this correction and information!

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your comment and thoughts. There's no need to close this topic anymore since I think Marius S.L.'s suggestion is what will answer all questions and once, so I've accepted his answer.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: And indeed the logistic density matches exactly with the simple model I described in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354969/50073).

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Although you're of course right that this question depends on epidemiology to answer properly, the simple mathematical model I described in the link is surprisingly accurate (within each time interval of roughly constant behaviour).

Comment: @user21820 You are likely correct, but I think that my original objection stands:  the question is overly broad.  I'm not sure what the essential, singular, *mathematical* question is here.  Also, I generally object to being required to follow a link in order to understand what a question is asking. :\

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Ah yes of course; images should have been put in the question itself. But in general mathematical modelling is always nebulous, and by the time we get a precise mathematical question the "modelling" part is gone. Not saying that this question is on-topic though, since it is clearly more about epidemiology than mathematics.

Comment: @user21820 I've edited the question to include the image, which is, at least, some improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a SIR model, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model

And there are simulators on the internet, e.g.
http://www.public.asu.edu/~hnesse/classes/sir.html

For the current outbreak, you can find data here:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/sascom/2020/03/10/using-data-visualization-to-track-the-coronavirus-outbreak/
They leap a bit but describe the current situation quite well.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the SIR model, it seems to me this is what I was looking for! :)